# Wolfram Mathematica to Latex - array not fully retaining precision

Tags: arrays, latex, wolfram-mathematica

I've got a set of data that I've arranged in an array within `mathematica`. The energy value should be as shown below when I copy as `LaTex` format:

> Theta Phi Energy(Hartree)
>
> 1.5329 & -1.5708 & -2775.20972374594 \\
>
> 1.53476   & -1.25646  & -2775.209669993 \\
>
> 1.54014   & -0.942167 & -2775.20947403366 \\

What I'm actually getting when I copy:

> 1.5329 & -1.5708 & -2775.21  \\
>
> 1.53476 & -1.25646 & -2775.21 \\
>
> 1.54014 & -0.942167 & -2775.21 \\

I've done multiple data sets and have gotten it to work for all but one. There seems to be a set of 100 points that keep truncating. I've attempted the following code:

```
PESdatatable316 = {{"Theta", "Phi", "Energy(Hartree)"}};

 Do[
 PESdatatable316 = Append[PESdatatable316, {th316[[i]], phi316[[i]], NumberForm[energies316[[i]], 15]}], {i, 1, 30}]

TableForm[PESdatatable316]
```

where:

```
energies316 = Flatten[{energies100,energies216},1]
```

The issue seems to be within 'energies100'. The values were put in with 12 digits but truncate to 6 when I call the values.

Example:

> energies100[[1]]

will output:

> -2775.21

'NumberForm' corrects the values within `mathematica` but when I copy to `LaTex` form it reverts back to the truncated values.

Any ideas on how I can get these values to what they're supposed to be?

Comment: Try export https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TeX.html

Comment: Perhaps relevant info https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results A little experimentation with that seems to show that using InputForm might give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you create a simple example that demonstates the issue?

Comment: Thanks Bill! While InputForm didn't fix the problem. There was the following code:SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision -> 15] however, while it seemed to fix precision in Mathematica, when I go to copy as LaTex it still truncates the values.

Comment: Regarding agentp's suggestion of exporting the values, I used the ExportString and while it does give me the table in LaTex format it's still truncating the values to the wrong precision.

Answer (score 1):

A solution has been found:

the use of 'TeXForm' with a 'NumberForm' nested inside results in the correct precision and can be copied with no issues arising.